# passing form post with WYSIWYG

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to pass form values through post form but nothing shows.

using this HTML5 Text Editor http://suyati.github.io/line-control/
I'm using this method for form and php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo $_POST['txtEditor'];
}
?>
```

html form i am using

```
                 <form method="post">
                   <textarea name="txtEditor" id="txtEditor" ></textarea>
                   <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
                 </form>
```

and the java script is

```
<script src="WYSIWYG-Text-Editor/editor.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txtEditor").Editor();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have checked the doc and apparently you need to set the value by yourself, here is a solution:

Add some code to your initialization code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txtEditor").Editor();
        $('form').submit(function () {
            $('#txtEditor').val($('#txtEditor').Editor('getText'));
        });
        $('#txtEditor').Editor('setText', $('#txtEditor').val());
    });
</script>
```

On form submit we actually set the textarea value with what the user input in the WYSISWYG.

In the next line of code we set the value of the WYSISWYG with what value comes in the textarea (as you requested in your comment).

Comment: No problem, one note please you better don't add the script as I said but put the form submit code just after your code which initialize the Editor: `$("#txtEditor").Editor();`. So we don't need redundant code cause `jQuery(function ($) {` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() {`.

Comment: yes i did ... but one Q dear after i post the form i want the result comes again the textarea <textarea name="getText" id="txtEditor" ><?php if(isset($_POST['getText'])){ echo $_POST['getText']; } ?></textarea> but nothing shows